# Express - Passing data to all routes

Tags: node.js, express

Hi is there a 'express' specific way to make some global app data available to all my routes?
Or is it a case of just using an module.exports statement?

Any pointers more than welcome.
Node noob - btw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set a global object that is also available in your layout

*app.js*

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('view options', {pageTitle: ''});
});

app.get('/',function(request, response){
  response.app.settings['view options'].pageTitle = 'Hello World';
  response.render('home');
});
```

*layout.jade*

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body!= body
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `app.set()` in the setup portion of your app to make it available to each request. The app object is available via `req.app` in your routes.

Personally, I like to do an `app.set('name', obj);` in the setup and in the routes I access it via `req.app.settings.name`.

Comment: You mean res.app not req.app isn't?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a dynamic helper to pass data to all views.

*app.js*

```
// Dynamic Helpers
app.dynamicHelpers({
    appSettings: function(req, res){
        return {name:"My App", version:"0.1"};
    }
});
```

Now on your views you can use it like this (I used ejs on this example but it should work with jade or any other view engine):

*view.ejs*

```
<%= appSettings.name %> 
<%= appSettings.version %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The downside of your answer is that for each request you will process the helper. For static data like version, `app.set('view options', someData)` is better suited. DynamicHelpers are for dynamic data.